# How to add '[]' to form element name in Zend_Form?

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

I am creating form elements like this

```
    $elements = array();

    $element = $this->CreateElement('checkbox', 'field[0]' );
    $element->setLabel( 'MyField1' );
    $element->setAttrib( 'checked', true );
    $elements[] = $element;

    $element = $this->CreateElement('checkbox', 'field[1]' );    
    $element->setLabel( 'MyField2' );
    $element->setAttrib( 'checked', true );
    $elements[] = $element;

    $this->addElements( $elements );
```

But it is setting `name='field0'` and `name='field1'` instead of `name='field[0]'` and `name='field[1]'`

How can we add `[]` in elements names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiCheckbox

Answer (score 2):

i read 2 kind of solutions one is `setElementsBelongTo` other one is `setIsArray` but the solutions are not comfortable for me why they block brackets i don't understand.why why why?
I think one way is just edit filter function to allow brackets.

Answer (score 1):

i think its not support in zend form only in :

```
Zend_Form_SubForm
```

[like](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2563)

```
$foo = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
$foo->setElementsBelongTo('foo')
    ->setElements(array(
        'bar' => 'text',
        'baz' => 'text'
    ));
echo $foo;
```

wich give you :

```
<input type="text" name="foo[bar]" id="foo.bar" value="" />
<input type="text" name="foo[baz]" id="foo.baz" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See 
http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Form-Element-set-name-allowBrackets-td679084.html

So, first off, names are not allowed to have brackets internally so that
a variety of other features will work (overloading access, primarily).

That said, you *can* force brackets to appear in the output in a couple
of different ways.

- If you want brackets for allowing multiple values to be captured --
  i.e., a name like 'foo[]' -- turn on the isArray property:

  ```
  $element->setIsArray(true); // or pass a true value to the
                              // "isArray" key during
                              // instantiation
  ```
- If you want the value to be a key in another value, e.g.,
  "bar[foo]", then you need to tell the element it belongs to another
  value:

  ```
  $element->setBelongsTo('bar'); // or pass the value to the
                                 // 'belongsTo' key during
                                 // instantiation
  ```
- If you use sub forms, array notation happens by default; all
  elements "belongTo" the name of the sub form

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$file = $this->createElement('file', 'myImgUpload');
$file->setAttrib('name', 'myImgUpload[]');
```

Btw: in `Zend_Form_Element::setName()` the methode `Zend_Form_Element::filterName()` strip the brackets